# Custom Gutenberg block is not showing up in inserter dialog

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to build the simplest of custom Gutenberg block by referring the handbook https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/blocks/writing-your-first-block-type/.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
wp-content
   plugins
      gutenberg-bolierplate-block
         block.js
         gutenberg-boilerplate-block.php
```

**Content of `gutenberg-boilerplate-block.php`**

```
<?php
function gutenberg_bolierplate_block() {
    wp_register_script(
        'gutenberg-boilerplate-block-es5',
        plugins_url( 'block.js', __FILE__ ),
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element' )
    );

    register_block_type( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-block/hello-world', array(
        'editor_script' => 'gutenberg-boilerplate-block-es5',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_bolierplate_block' );
```

**Content of `block.js`**

```
var el = wp.elements.createElement,
    registerBlockType = wp.blocks.registerBlockType,
    blockStyle = { backgroundColor: '#900', color: '#fff', padding: '20px' };

registerBlockType ( 'gutenberg-boilerplate-block/hello-world', {
        title: 'Hello World',
        icon: 'universal-access-alt',
        category: 'common',
        edit: function() {
            return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello editor' );
        },
        save:  function() {
            return el( 'p', { style: blockStyle }, 'Hello saved content' );
        }
} );
```

But the block is **never showing up in the inserter dialog**. I tried in different browsers and also by clearing cache. This is the first time I am trying my hand with this and absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong.

Any suggestion would greatly help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enqueue your scripts using `enqueue_block_assets` action, like this:

```
add_action('enqueue_block_assets', 'gutenberg_bolierplate_block');
```

Second, you should use JSX with modern JavaScript development environment to write your blocks easily.

I made a boilerplate for my personal use that you can use: https://github.com/HardeepAsrani/gutenberg-boilerplate

You just need to run `npm install` to install dependencies, and then `npm run dev` or `npm run build` to transpile the code.

If you want to  continue this way then you will have to edit the first line of your code from

```
var el = wp.elements.createElement,
```

to

```
var el = wp.element.createElement,
```

As it uses wrong module name.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is:

var el = wp.element**s**.createElement

I'd recommend checking the console often as you are developing your block. As errors like that one will often show up there first.